# CSV HELPER Setting the max number of split to 3

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am mapping the contents of a 3 column CSV file to an object, but I am not sure of the contents of the last column because it can contain my delimiter. So, I would like to map by setting the number of split to 3:

```
public MyDataAutoMapper()
{      
    Map(m => m.Id).NameIndex(0);
    Map(m => m.IdDaTa).Index(1);
    Map(m => m.xmlData).Index(2);
}
```

Comment: A field can't contain a field delimiter, unless the text is wrapped in a text qualifier character, eg `"`. "1,2"` is a single text value. `1,2` is *two* fields. Whatever code generates that CSV file should be modified to use text qualifiers

Comment: If the last field contains XML data though, double quotes in the XML data itself will have to be encoded, or the text qualifier should be a character that can't appear in XML,eg §. Why not create a proper XML file with the data you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped CSV HELPER, and I have used a simple split that ignores the contents of the last column

char[] Delimiters = new char[] { ',' };

var splitedString = line.Split(Delimiters, 3);

Comment: You will run into issues when your field contains a comma.

Comment: I'm sure my first two columns do not contain a comma, and setting the split to 3, it does not check the last column